# How include a Feynman diagram in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, include, feynmf

I have a bunch of Feynman diagrams constructed with "feynmp" that I would like to include in a beamer (presentation mode). I know Tikz works but then I have to redraw each and every diagram from scratch...no time for that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you export them to pdf format? If yes, you can include in beamer.

Comment: The problem is solved with the package "feynmp-auto". 

Please see [this page][1].


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141886/feynmp-together-with-beamer

Comment: You can (and should) post your solution as an answer - except that you seem to have asked this question twice ...