# Feynman Diagram error in Beamer TeX document

Tags: beamer, feynman, physics

I have a paper where my Feynman diagram is working, but when I transfer it to the Beamer .tex file, it gives me the following error:

```
**LaTeX Error: Can not include graphics of type: mps.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.xxx \end{frame}**
```

The code that I'm using is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comment environment
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\title{Tetraquarks}
\subtitle{SU(3) symmetry breaking}
\date{\today}
\author{A}
\institute{UB}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{UB.png}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{frame}{QQ Interaction}

\begin{equation*}
\hspace{-3mm}i\mu =\bar v\left(p_2,\sigma_2\right)\gamma^{\mu}v(q_2,\tau_2) ig(\Lambda)(T^{\gamma})_{jl}\Big(\frac{-ig\mu\Lambda}{k^2}\Big)(T^{\alpha})_{ki}ig(\Lambda)\bar u\left(q_1,\sigma_1\right)\gamma^{\Lambda}u(p_1,\sigma_1)
\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(140,80)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$p_1,\sigma_1,i$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$q_1,\tau_1,k$}{i2}
\fmflabel{$p_2,\sigma_2,j$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$q_2,\tau_2,l$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\gamma$}{v1}
\fmflabel{$\alpha$}{v2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v2,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v1,o1}
\fmf{gluon,label=$(T_{\alpha ' \alpha}^{a})(T_{\gamma \gamma '}^{a})$}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{center}
\caption{Feynman diagram for the quark-quark interaction.}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation*}
(T_a)^{\alpha}_{\alpha '}(T_a)^{\gamma '}_{\gamma}=\frac{1}{2}({\delta}^{\gamma '}_{\alpha '}{\delta}^{\alpha}_{\gamma}-\frac{1}{N_c}{\delta}^{\alpha}_{\alpha '}{\delta}^{\gamma '}_{\gamma})
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I hope someone can give me an advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried with `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`? See e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141900/36296

Comment: I got the error `Can not include graphics of type: mps` when using `latex` rather than `pdflatex`. Removing the line `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}` fixed. it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `feynmp-auto`, so Metapost is run automatically *and* the `.mps` problem is coped with. Note the `fragile` option for the frame with the diagram.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comment environment
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\title{Tetraquarks}
\subtitle{SU(3) symmetry breaking}
\date{\today}
\author{A}
\institute{UB}
%\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{UB.png}} % I haven't it

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{QQ Interaction}

\begin{equation*}
\hspace{-3mm}
i\mu =\bar v(p_2,\sigma_2\gamma^{\mu}v(q_2,\tau_2) 
ig(\Lambda)(T^{\gamma})_{jl}\left(\frac{-ig\mu\Lambda}{k^2}\right)
(T^{\alpha})_{ki}ig(\Lambda)\bar u(q_1,\sigma_1)\gamma^{\Lambda}u(p_1,\sigma_1)
\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(140,80)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$p_1,\sigma_1,i$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$q_1,\tau_1,k$}{i2}
\fmflabel{$p_2,\sigma_2,j$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$q_2,\tau_2,l$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\gamma$}{v1}
\fmflabel{$\alpha$}{v2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v2,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v1,o1}
\fmf{gluon,label=$(T_{\alpha ' \alpha}^{a})(T_{\gamma \gamma '}^{a})$}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\bigskip

\caption{Feynman diagram for the quark-quark interaction.}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation*}
(T_a)^{\alpha}_{\alpha '}(T_a)^{\gamma '}_{\gamma}=
\frac{1}{2}({\delta}^{\gamma '}_{\alpha '}{\delta}^{\alpha}_{\gamma}-
\frac{1}{N_c}{\delta}^{\alpha}_{\alpha '}{\delta}^{\gamma '}_{\gamma})
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, there is a new package called [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) which works perfectly fine inside Beamer presentation.  It also supports momentum arrows which might be useful in your case (though at the same time, too much information can make the diagram look cluttered).

Anyway, I have adapted the example you gave to use Ti*k*Z-Feynman and show how you can use momentum arrows as well.  Notice of course that this works perfectly in Beamer with no need for fragile frames.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{QQ Interaction}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle={\(\sigma_{1}, i\)}]
        -- [fermion, momentum=\(p_{1}\)] a
        -- [fermion, rmomentum=\(q_{1}\)] i2 [particle={\(\tau_{1}, k\)}],
      a [label=180:\(\alpha\)] -- [gluon] b [label=0:\(\gamma\)],
      f1 [particle={\(\sigma_{2}, j\)}]
        -- [fermion, rmomentum'=\(p_{2}\)] b
        -- [fermion, momentum'=\(q_{2}\)] f2 [particle={\(\tau_{2}, l\)}],
    };
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
      i1 [particle={\(p_{1}, \sigma_{1}, i\)}]
        -- [fermion] a
        -- [fermion] i2 [particle={\(q_{1}, \tau_{1}, k\)}],
      a [label=180:\(\alpha\)]
        -- [gluon, edge label=\(T^{a}_{\alpha'\alpha} \quad T^{a}_{\gamma\gamma'}\)]
        b [label=0:\(\gamma\)],
      f1 [particle={\(p_{2}, \sigma_{2}, j\)}]
        -- [fermion] b
        -- [fermion] f2 [particle={\(q_{2}, \tau_{2}, l\)}],
    };
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Isnt it possible to make the gluon larger and include the T•T transfer operator tensors on top of it, for the graphic with momentum?

Comment: @Jackson Yeah, Ti*k*Z-Feynman is built on top of Ti*k*Z, so you can quite easily customize everything.  I didn't put the T•T along with the momentum arrows because I thought it looked a little too cramped, but please feel free to adapt the above example to get exactly what you want.